# Don't understand what array-1 means

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a problem with understanding this code, especially the "vet-1" part.
What does it mean? What item of the array does it return?

I found this exercise while practicing for an exam in my first year of University and I wondered if it has a solution. It is not my own code. Thanks!

```
#include <stdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void change(int m, int n[7]);

int main(){
    int vet[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    change(vet[4], vet-1);
    change(0, &vet[4]);
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) cout << vet[i];
    return 0;
}

void change(int m, int n[7]) {
    (*(n+m))--; m++; n--;
}
```

Comment: I think it is UB as `vet-1` is out of bound array (even if not deferenced).

Comment: btw afaik C has no iostream header nor a namespace std

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes your're correct. The only exception would be `vet + 5`.

Comment: It probably tries to use the fact that with C arrays [`a[b]` is the same as `*(a + b)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a), but fails by going out of bounds.

Comment: That won't even compile due to syntax errors

Comment: In general, subtracting one from a pointer is analogous to adding one to a pointer: it moves to the element just before.  If the pointer points somewhere within an array, this can be perfectly legal and perfectly meaningful; it's a problem only if the pointer is already pointing at the beginning of the array.  In the posted code fragment, however, `v` does point to the beginning of the array (it *is* the array!), so it's undefined.  The code has other problems, and should be thrown away, not learned from.  Any textbook or course that presented this code for instruction is suspect.

Comment: I'm assuming this code is from some book/online tutorial/teacher/school/.... . This code is a good example how to "NOT TEACH" programing in C or C++. I recommend change source.

Comment: @MarekR Yes it was 4 years ago so I don't remember exactly from which resource I found it, but it was my first year of University and this was an exercise I found somewhere. Don't know why lately this question is getting popular and getting downvoted :D

Comment: @GiulioMattolin someone edited your question so it was shown to me. Didn't notice that it is old.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`vet - 1` is an attempt at referring to the pointer to the element *just before* `vet[0]`.

Actually the behaviour on doing that is *undefined*. So the entire program is undefined.

Nothing to understand here; move on!

Comment: _"move on!"_ quite literally. Especially if it was an interview question.

Comment: I thought the same, but why the program print something instead of giving a run-time error?

Comment: @FrancescoMarzetta: Because when you use `[]` to access an element, C++ assumes you know what you're doing. If you want an exception to be thrown, then use `.at`.

Comment: @FrancescoMarzetta That's part of undefined behavior.  The program *might* crash, but it doesn't have to.